# Calculate the translation matrix to move a vertex to origin

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a set of points in some space `(x,y,z,w)` and I want to translate one of those points to the origin `(x', y', z', 1) = (0,0,0,1)`. After finding the translation matrix for one point, I want to apply the same matrix to all the other points so that they are translated the same amount.

I have written the following function to generate a translation matrix:

```
def get_translation_matrix4(x,y,z):
    return np.array([[1,0,0,x], [0,1,0,y], [0,0,1,z],[0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I have a function that applies the translation to vertices in an object. `data` contains a `(8, 4)` shaped matrix with each row being a vertex of the object.

```
def apply_transform(self, m4):

    for i in range(0, len(self.data)):
        vertex = self.data[i]

        # matrix multiplication
        vertex = vertex @ m4
        self.data[i] = vertex

    self.__init_from_data(self.data)
```

I'm attempting to apply the translation matrix like this:

```
p = myObject.point
distance_to_origin = origin - p
trans_x, trans_y, trans_z, _ = distance_to_origin
translation_mat = get_translation_matrix4(trans_x, trans_y, trans_z)
myObject.apply_transform(translation_mat)
```

After calling `apply_transform` on my object, and after plotting it, there is no change in position.

Comment: shouldn't that be `m4 @ vertex`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer that did the trick thank you! Also, do you mind checking if `origin - p` is the right way to generate the translation matrix? First time doing this kind of stuff haha

Comment: Looks about ok to me. But you can sanity-check yourself: If you apply your matrix to `p`, do you get the expected result?

Comment: @PaulPanzer ah yeah I need a better way of testing my code, rather than matplotlib. Thanks for your help!